Huion tablet driver pressure inputs not registering
I've got a new laptop and after a long while, I decided to use my tablet but I forgot I don't have drivers installed.
I downloaded the new drivers for my H640P tablet. Everything setup, all good. It worked, pen worked, features worked, but the touch sensitivity didn't register inside the test.
I decided to see if it registered in any graphics program. No luck either. I started realizing it was behaving like a mouse, not a windows ink device. I tried unchecking and rechecking the tick-box for enable Windows Ink, no luck.
I restarted my computer, no luck. Reinstall the driver, no luck. Install the legacy driver for it, and I see pressure sensitivity working inside the tester box?
But still, no Windows ink and no pressure sensitivity in other programs.
I honestly don't know what to do, but I really want to get it to work as a Windows ink device.

Is the Pen Tablet Driver running (C:\Program Files\TabletDriver\TabletDriver.exe, on this PC)? To properly run PenPressureTest, it must be started from within that application, as shown below.

Double-click the Graphics Tablet icon in the Taskbar to show the app window, then click Pen Pressure Test button.
Also, which image editing applications have you tried? MS Paint, for example, is not pressure-sensitive, Krita is, and Paint.Net requires Support TabletPC be turned on in the Huion dialog, above, as well as the Pressure sensitivity selection in the Paint.Net toolbar.

The Pen Pressure Test included with the huion driver works perfectly fine, and I usually use Microsoft Whiteboard and OneNote and they respond to pressure but now they aren't. Even on skribbl.io, it used to register pressure, now it doesn't

I found the similar issue for all Huion's tablets with driver version 14.x and aboved (currently on version 15.x). After doing some research, I stumble upon a reddit post suggested disable window ink on huion driver's and using different driver to run winink (I use OpenTabletDriver as the reddit post suggested, the setup look somethink like this Huion winink driver setup. Wonder if there are any option to use on the original huion apps, because this allow all tablet function to work, but changing configuration will be hassle and can cause issue such as requiring monitor sync in both apps.
